# Cognito unable to signup users that have unconfirmed status already

Tags: amazon-cognito

A Cognito User Pool is configured for the users to use their "email address" to sign up and sign in.

If a user signs up with the email of someone else then that email will get stuck in UNCONFIRMED state and the owner will not be able to use it appropriately.

Having said that let me provide an example with the following scenario:

1. User signs in with an email address the user doesn't own, let's say it is *someone@mail.com*. In this step (registration form) some more data is sent like organization name, and user full name.
2. Verification code is sent to the email
3. Now the user that owns *someone@email.com* wants to create an account (maybe some days in the future), so he goes and fills the registration form but an error is thrown by cognito `{"__type":"UsernameExistsException","message":"An account with the given email already exists."}`

Thinks to consider:
 * If the email already exists but is in unconfirmed state then provide the user the option to resend the link. This option is not optimal because additional data might be already in the user profile as the *1st step* exemplifies.
 * A custom lambda can be done to delete the unconfirmed user before signup or as a maintenance process every day, but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

> There is also this configuration under *Policies* in cognito consol:  "How quickly should user accounts created by administrators expire if not used?", but as he name implies this setting will only apply to users if they are invited by admins.

Is there a proper solution for this predicament?

Comment: I think the way it currently works in correct. The options you have are:1) Admin has to delete the user manually 2) User signs in with the password received, then corrects his information

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Cognito has provided pre-signup triggers for these functionality and auto signup also.Your thought is the same way as i have implemented that according to the cognito documentations.

Here I am using the amplify/cli which is the toolchain for my development purpose hence the lambda function used in the trigger is as below:

`

```
"use strict";
console.log("Loading function");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
  uuid = require("uuid");
var cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const modifiedEvent = event;
  // check that we're acting on the right trigger
  if (event.triggerSource === "PreSignUp_SignUp") {
    var params = {
      UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
      Username: event.userName
    };
    cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminGetUser(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } // an error occurred
      else {
        console.log("cognito service", data);
        if (data.UserStatus == "UNCONFIRMED") {
          cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminDeleteUser(params, function(
            err,
            data
          ) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
            // an error occurred
            else console.log("Unconfirmed user delete successful ");
           // successful response
          });
        }
        // successful response
      }
    });
    return;
  }
  // Throw an error if invoked from the wrong trigger
  callback('Misconfigured Cognito Trigger '+ event.triggerSource);
};
```

`

this will actually check and delete if the status is UNCONFIRMED using the aws-sdk methods adminGetUser and adminDeleteUser

hope this will help ;)

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. When I try to sign up as an existing, but UNCONFIRMED user - the Pre sign-up trigger lambda is never invoked. I just get UsernameExistsException back from Cognito.

Comment: I think it might setting up of trigger is the not proper can you please check the cloud watch logs while the trigger is invoked and please set up the roles for the trigger with admin access and try again cause full access will allow the admin get user and delete user will work

Comment: I have checked the logs. The pre-signup trigger fires the lambda just fine if the user doesn't exist. But if the user exists (Confirmed or Unconfirmed) the trigger never fires, and the UsernameExists error is sent back to the client. 

Maybe it's because we're using the option where the user uses their confirmed email/mobile phone number as username. Maybe that behavior is different. But I know the pre-signup trigger is not firing when a user exists for us.

Comment: Okay might be the point but there is one possibility of the problem,which is the sdk cognitoIdentityProvider is not working as expected hence the data of the user name and the cognito pool id that is provided might coincide.I have used email address at that region of code, plus can u please check that the lambda has sufficent role policy to access adminget users which is of full access capability . If it doesnot work ill look up the issue in my domain thanks for the quotes

Comment: The lambda does have the correct role access, and works fine if the user does not exist yet. It tries to look up the user in Cognito and returns no users. However if the user does exist, I never see any log entries for the lambda (including the START log that AWS fires with every lambda). So it's not even firing at all in the case when a user who already exists tries to sign up. I think the problem is with the trigger, not the lambda. I did use your code btw - just not in the signup trigger. I have to call it from the front end if it gets the UserExists error back from the Sign Up call.

Comment: I can confirm this method does not work. The PreSignUp trigger is *not* invoked if there is a collision with an *un*confirmed user in the user pool.

Comment: I can also confirm this method is not being invoked if there is a collision. My userpool is also set up like @MattS 's

Comment: thanks for letting me know that this won't work this method was derived 2 years back a lot of things has been changed. Kindly please let me know if any of you guys get a proper answer once again thanks @MikeFogel

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by setting ForceAliasCreation=True.  This would allow the real email owner to confirm their account.  The draw back is that you end up with 2 users.  One CONFIRMED user and another UNCONFIRMED user.

To clean this up, I have a lambda function that calls list-users with filter for unconfirmed user and delete the accounts which were created before a certain period.  This function is triggered daily by CloudWatch.

Comment: from where you are setting ForceAliasCreation? I am not able to find this.

Answer (score -3):

change to confirm from unconfirm:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-confirm-sign-up \
--user-pool-id %aws_user_pools_web_client_id% \
--username %email_address%
```

Comment: This is a horrible idea. You are force-confirming users with emails they may not own.